# CentOS on Docker: How to install doc files?

Tags: centos, yum, docker

I’m trying to install the Kolab groupware in a Docker container based on CentOS 6.5. At first glance, the installation of the official packages seemed to work without problems. But afterwards, when I tried to run the setup script, several errors occurred. After doing some research, I found out, that the setup script tries to use an sql schema file, located in `/usr/share/doc/kolab-webadmin-3.1.5`. According to `repoquery -l kolab-webadmin`, the sql file is indeed included in the package. It is, however, not installed.

I suspect that this is somehow a “feature” of Docker, which tries to avoid the installation of unnecessary documentation files into the container, but could not find any information about it.

Is there a way to install the missing files through yum?

---

**Update**:

Here is a minimal example to illustrate the problem:
First create a new centos container:

```
docker run -t -i centos:centos6 /bin/bash
```

Inside, install the yum-utils package:

```
yum install -y yum-utils
```

Afterwards, if you use repoquery to inspect the contents of the yum-utils package

```
repoquery -l yum-utils
```

you will notice that the package contains files under /usr/share/doc/yum-utils-1.1.30.
This folder, however, does not exist.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question by adding more details: what **image** are you using, how do you instantiate your **container** (and if those terms don't mean much to you please consult the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/)). If possible, please quote and state what Dockerfile you are using, based on what image.

Comment: There is nothing as such with `docker` as restricting `yum` to install some packages or files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out why the docs are not installed: it is not a feature of Docker but of the CentOS Docker image. Yum and rpm configs both contain options that prevent the installation. They may be disabled by adding the following lines to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN sed -i '/excludedocs/d' /etc/rpm/macros.imgcreate
RUN sed -i '/nodocs/d' /etc/yum.conf
```

Comment: Wow! You saved me **a lot** of trouble and time. I had exactly the same problem on Ubuntu. In my case `.deb` package had multiple sample configuration files in `/usr/share/doc/package-name/examples` directory (which I needed), but for unknown reasons they were installed at all! It turned out that Ubuntu Docker image has `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes` file which explicitly [excludes](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/issues/126) `/usr/share/man/*`, `/usr/share/doc/*`, `/usr/share/doc/*/copyright`, `/usr/share/doc/*/changelog.Debian.*`.